# JavaScript regex needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
<tr class="AttCardFooter" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#E1EAFE'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='Transparent'">...etc etc.. new lines etc.. <td title="Saldo+">33:33</td><td title="Saldo-">22:22</td> .. etc etc...
```

I need JavaScript regex that will grab these two fields 33:33 and 22:22
All that I have tried fails because  of new line characters.
If anyone knows how to accomplish that I would be very grateful.

Comment: It's generally considered a bad idea to use regex to parse HTML. I'd recommend you use something like xpath instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: There needs to be a count of how many JavaScript regex questions are about parsing HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201952). I guess your piece of html is an `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` of some element. Instead of parsing html with regexp do this:

```
var el = document.querySelector("tr.AttCardFooter"); // I guess you have that variable already
for (var i=0; i<el.cells.length; i++) {
     var td = el.cells[i];
     if (td.title == "Saldo+")
         var positiveSaldo = td.innerText;
     else if (td.title == "Saldo-")
         var negativeSaldo = td.innerText;
}
alert("Voila:\n"+positiveSaldo+"\n"+negativeSaldo);
```

You may improve this with your favorite libraries dom functions. For example in jQuery it would be something like

```
 var el = $("tr.AttCardFooter");
 var positiveSaldo = el.find('td[title="Saldo+"]').text();
 var negativeSaldo = el.find('td[title="Saldo-"]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to process the new line characters.  Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myRegExp, Pattern.DOT_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib and add /s flag so the dot matches new lines.

http://xregexp.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions **cannot** parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201952)

If the table row is already part of your document, then there's no need to do anything fancy.  Use the DOM to extract the values you need -- [Bergi has great suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982532/201952).

If the string comes from somewhere else, consider using a hidden `<div>` and set its `innerHTML`.  The browser handles parsing the string; you then use DOM methods to extract the values you need.

Of course, if that "somewhere else" is untrusted input (third party site, user input, etc), you can't just use a hidden `<div>` due to the security problems of blindly sticking potentially executable code into your page.  Instead, you need to sandbox this step in an `<iframe>` running on a different Origin.